# Kibana - add a listener

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have ELK installed, and all works fine. I have one index that always receives logs from Logstash. 
Sometimes, Logstash stops working (every second month or so), and nothing comes to the index.

I was wondering is there a way to query the index (some interval), if it does not have any entries to produce some kind of event, which I will handle.

For example, query that index every 10 mins, and if there are no logs, then create an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for ELK's internal tools. There is the Elasticsearch Xpack plugin that gives watchers and notifications. But if that's not a requirement, you can write a nodeJS server that querys the last 5 minutes or so, and you can write the exact notification you need.
I hope I could help.

Comment: Xpack is not an option at this time. However, I like your idea for Nodejs server. Thanks.